# Firebase Storage download task is not completing after the app has spent some time in the background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am downloading an image from Firebase storage as follows:

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
// Create a storage reference from our storage service
let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: "MY_STORAGE_URL")

let imageRef = storageRef.child("Path_to_image")

// Download image in memory 
let downloadTask = imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) {
    (data, error) -> Void in

    if (error != nil) {

        //Handle the error 

    } else {

        guard let imageData = data else {
            print("Unable to unwrap image data.")
            return
        }

        let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
        //Do some stuff with the image 

    }

}
```

I am also monitoring what happens with the download using the following observers:

```
// Observe changes in status
downloadTask.observe(.resume) { (snapshot) -> Void in
    // Download resumed, also fires when the download starts
}

downloadTask.observe(.pause) { (snapshot) -> Void in
    // Download paused
}

downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in
    // Download reported progress
}

downloadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) -> Void in
    // Download completed successfully
}

downloadTask.observe(.failure) { (snapshot) -> Void in
    //Download failed 
}
```

This all works just fine when the app is first started. However, I am getting problems if the app enters the background and I play around with some other applications (Facebook, Twitter, etc.), then bring the app back to the foreground. I also have problems if I leave the app open and running in the foreground for greater than or equal to 1 hour.

The problem is that the completion handler in `let downloadTask = imageRef.data(withMaxSize:` blah blah blah (in the first block of code above) is never called. If the completion handler is never called, I can never unwrap the data and attempt to use the image in my application.

Also, in the `downloadTask` observers, the only completion handlers that get fired are `.resume` and `.progress`. The `.success` or `.failure` events are never triggered. This seems to be a Firebase Storage bug to me, but I am not sure. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? I don't understand why the code would work just fine from a fresh launch, but then after some time in the foreground or after some time in the background the image download stops working. Thanks in advance for any input you may have.

Comment: I don't see the `enque()` method being triggered.

Comment: My example is pretty much straight from the docs. They do not call the `enqueue()` method there. Can you please explain why this is necessary?

Comment: Don't you have to do special things if you want to run in the background in iOS?  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

This is currently the expected behavior, unfortunately. Firebase Storage (at present) is foreground only: if the app is backgrounded, we haven't persisted the upload URL, and can't upload in the background nor restart it after it gets out of the background, so it probably is killed by the OS and the item isn't uploaded.

It's The Next Big Thing™ we'd like to tackle ([our Android SDK makes it possible](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes), though not easy), but unfortunately for now we haven't made more progress on this.

As a bit of a side note, your observers won't exist after the activity change--`downloadTask` is gone once the app is backgrounded, so when it comes back into the foreground, we basically need a method that retrieves all tasks that are currently backgrounded, and allows you to hook observers back up. Something like:

```
FIRStorage.storage().backgroundedTasks { (tasks) -> Void in
  // tasks is an array of upload and download tasks
  // not sure if it needs to be async
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike. Just to be clear and make sure we understand each other, I am not trying to background the application in the middle of downloading a large image. I just want these methods to work whenever they are called while the application is in the foreground. Is this really the expected behavior? Logging out and logging back in does not fix the issue. I have to fully restart the app in order to start downloading images again. This is very frustrating for my users. Is there any work around?

Comment: I must not have understood your question fully, sorry. To be more clear, it sounds like all the observers and the completion block work fine while in the foreground, but the issues only start to appear after either a very long time in the foreground, or if the app is backgrounded then appears in the foreground. Do you happen to have a sample app and repro for this so we can debug it locally? I can't seem to make this happen reliably.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately, I do not have a public repo for the app. The easiest way I've found to recreate the error is: 
1. Launch the app in the Xcode simulator. Verify its working as expected. 
2. Wait one hour. Do not touch anything in the app for one hour. 
3. Attempt to download some images. The images will not load. I know this is time consuming but it is the only surefire way I've found to recreate the error.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Any more progress to uploading in the background using Firebase Storage for iOS? Or at least a sessionUri like Android so I can resume uploads after a backgroundTask is killed. If it is not possible I will have to use another solution using URLSession which allows the app to be suspended or terminated while the upload continues.